# How can I generate a reflectance map using a perspective camera?

Tags: transformations, perspective

In simple words, a [reflectance map](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-3-030-63416-2_546) is a function `f(n)` that map a surface patch with normal `n` to its reflected radiance given a fixed viewing direction. According to [1]:

> The amount of light reflected by a surface element in a given direction depends on its optical properties, on its microstructure, and on the spatial and spectral distribution of the light sources. For many materials, the fraction of the total irradiance reflected toward the viewer depends only on the surface orientation. Horn [1] introduced the reflectance map as a way to specify scene radiance as a function of surface orientation, given the following simplifying assumptions:
>
> 1. The direction toward the viewer is the same at every visible point on the surface. This holds when image projection is orthographic.
> 2. The direction toward the light source is the same at every visible point on the surface. This holds for point light sources at infinity and for parallel (i.e., collimated) light sources.

Thus, it is trivial to synthesize a reflectance map using an orthographic camera. As the primary rays from the camera are all parallel to each other. To syhthesize a reflectance map from it, one only needs to store the pixel intensity and its corresponding shading normal in the camera space, both of which are readily available in the G-buffer.

My question is how can I synthesize a reflectance map from an image which is rendered using a perspective camera?

[1] https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-3-030-63416-2_546